# How to resolve Case sensitive issue while using sub query in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
  select * from  ur_username u 
   join ur_username_person up 
   on up.username_id=u.username_id  
   join ur_person p on up.person_id=p.person_id 
   join ur_system s on u.system_id=s.system_id 
   WHERE U.USERNAME IN  (select username from ur_username where system_id=349 and  status='DISABLED') AND U.STATUS='ACTIVE'
```

in the above code in where clause all the username from the sub query will be stored and I want the all username irrespective of case should be stored in the where clause i tried using (UPPER) but only getting upper case user names alone.
Please give any suggestions here.
For example in the sub query I am getting "ccku" as result but when it comes to where clause I want store both "ccku" and "CCKU" .

Please help me with the above issue

Comment: do you mean you can have multiple users with ther same username but one un lower case and one in upper case?

Comment: Yes exactly. This is the issue I am facing now Because of this issue some of the user details  are not fetching in this query

Comment: can you also have mixed case : like Ccku or cCku?

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO - Why did you delete your answer? I think it was correct; changing LIKE to IN and using UPPER on both sides. What was wrong with it?

Comment: it should be in not Like because I want every data and There is no mixed data only lower or upper case usernames are ther

Comment: @mathguy because it seems he want both result matching lower case and upper case. He has duplicates but with lowercase and uppercase differences, the upper will not work in this case it will consider them identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tried upper, did you do this in your where clause?

```
WHERE 
UPPER(U.USERNAME) IN
UPPER(select username from ur_username where system_id=349 and  status='DISABLED')
```

Comment: See his comment I don’t think that’s what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be super efficient but you might be able to check the subquery twice.  once using upper() and once using lower().

```
WHERE (upper(U.USERNAME) IN  (select username from ur_username where system_id=349 and  status='DISABLED')
    or lower(U.USERNAME) IN  (select username from ur_username where system_id=349 and  status='DISABLED'))
AND U.STATUS='ACTIVE'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have settings of SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON parameter as 'TRUE',
setting this parameter to 'FALSE' maybe solves your issue.

SQL> show parameter sec_case_sensitive_logon
SQL> alter system set sec_case_sensitive_logon=false scope=both;